# How to work with Spark dataframes after creating them in a list?

Tags: list, dataframe, pyspark

I've created multiple spark dataframes in a loop. But for some reason I cannot use them.

```py
genreslist = ['unknown', ... ,'Western']

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, LongType

schema = StructType([StructField("movie_id",LongType(),True)...StructField("Western",LongType(),True)])

d = {}

for name in genreslist:
    d[name] = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)
```

This is the list with dataframes:

```py
d
```

```py
'Action': DataFrame[movie_id: bigint, ..., Western: bigint],
 ...
 'unknown': DataFrame[movie_id: bigint, ..., Western: bigint]}
```

But I cannot work with exactly dataframe, for example:

```py
Action.printSchema()
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-d2848cc5d13e> in <module>()
----> 1 Action.printSchema()

NameError: name 'Action' is not defined
```

Looks like I need to "activate" these dataframes somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.
The correct way to work with dataframes in this case:

```
df['Action'].printSchema()

    root
 |-- movie_id: long (nullable = true)
 ...
 |-- Western: long (nullable = true)
```